# How can I access my D drive in Debian 9

Tags: debian

I was on Windows 10 system. Right before I installed Debian 9 and deleted Windows 10. While installing Debian I choose my C drive as primary partition to install Debian and my other drive, which was D drive, I chose "Do not use". But after installing Debian I can't see my D drive, I can only see my 40 GB partition of Debian system. My other space around 300 GB is lost I can't find it.

How can I access my D drive now?

Comment: Get a partitioning tool and find out which device it is (like `/dev/sda3` or so) and mount it using the File Explorer or `sudo mount`

Answer (score 1):

Because you chose “Do not use”, the partition is now not mounted automatically. That doesn’t mean all is lost, however!

Your partition is most likely NTFS, you cannot write to it from Linux by default. You’ll need NTFS-3G for that. Install this first.

To find its Linux device name, issue the `sudo fdisk -l` command. You’ll get something like this:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 5294E22E-B1FF-429E-B6D6-BB6F7BC4D343

Device         Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048       4095      2048     1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2       4096     266239    262144   128M Linux RAID
/dev/sda3     266240    8654847   8388608     4G Linux swap
/dev/sda4    8654848  113512447 104857600    50G Linux RAID
/dev/sda5  113512448  155455487  41943040    20G Linux RAID
/dev/sda6  155455488 1000215182 844759695 402.8G FreeBSD ZFS
```

Let’s say `/dev/sda4` is the partition you want to use. To mount it, you first need a mountpoint – a plain directory typically located in `/mnt`. Let’s use `/mnt/win-data`. Create it using this command:

```
mkdir /mnt/win-data
```

To mount your partition once, issue the following command:

```
mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda4 /mnt/win-data
```

You’ll probably want to make this change permanent. To do this, you’ll have to add an entry to `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/sda4   /mnt/win-data   ntfs-3g   defaults   0 0
```

Make sure not to change or remove any existing entries in `/etc/fstab` or your system may no longer boot.

You can learn more about NTFS-3G [here](https://www.tuxera.com/community/open-source-ntfs-3g/).

Answer (score 1):

If you like using GUI tools, an easy way would be to use [GNOME Disks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Disks) (aka `gnome-disks`) from the `gnome-disk-utility` package. It's included by default in many distributions & should show you an overview of any disks & their partitions.

[image]

Then you can click on the partition you want (your 300G data partition formerly known as "D") and edit it's mount options (in `/etc/fstab`) without having to use a text editor on `/etc/fstab` by hand. (You may have to run Gnome disks as root / with sudo/gksu/gksudo).

[image]

Finding the right partition should be fairly evident from their sizes & labels.

Choosing the mount point and adding other options on the line above "Mount Point" (like `ro` for read-only instead of `rw` for read-write)

---

If you're still in a terminal, I like the `lsblk` command for a quick overview of drives & partitions too, with a few extra options like:

```
lsblk -o +SIZE,LABEL,FSTYPE
```